# OOTB Spartacus SASS build is failing

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm having this issue below just today. would you know how to fix this? This is the SASS version installed in my Spartacus
sass "1.22.9"
sass-loader "7.2.0"
I'm using Angular8 and Spartacus 1.5

[image]

Comment: I found out this is due to an update of t the SASS hamburgers. See this link https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/issues/107

A workaround is you can either override in the package.json the hamburgers to update to old version or we can wait to update the OOTB Spartacus SASS to at least 1.33. I believe the 1.33 version is compatible with the latest hamburgers version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to build successfully in CCV2. I added the below code in my package.json and make sure to remove the package-lock.json or yarn.lock before doing yarn install.

```
"resolutions": {
    "hamburgers": "~1.1.3"
 }
```

It seems the SAP Spartacus SASS version is still in 1.22.9. However, the latest version of hamburgers requires at least a 1.33 sass version.

This is a workaround fix while waiting for the SAP Spartacus to fix this issue. Reference ticket: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/15389